# Pattern for encapsulating same process on different types of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two separate objects (classes) that have very similar properties (But not identical). However both have "Discount" property that I need to perform some type of operation on and return that specific object once that process completes.

```
Class1:
Name, Total, Discount, Prop1, Prop5 etc

Class2:
FirstName, TotalAmount, Discount, Prop5, Prop11 etc
```

I would like to inject either Class1 or Class2 into my service, perform some type of discount calculation and return an updated object with its discount property updated as well as Totals (Notice Total vs. TotalAmount)

Would I use a common Interface ie "IDiscount" that has a single property `Discount { get; set; }`? which both Class1 and Class2 inherit?

```
ServiceClass constructor:
MyService(IDiscount)
```

This way I could use Generics: 
class1 = MyService(Class1) OR MyService(Class2)

Is this the right approach? How would I handle updating Totals (these two are called differently in each class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Class1 and Class2 are similar objects with only a few things different, I would consider grouping their common properties (including Discount), fields, and methods into a parent class they both inherit from and have my method accept the parent type.  If Class1 and Class2 are dissimilar objects, I would consider using an interface and have my method accept that.

Think, too: how will I use this parent class or interface in the future?  Am I really designing things properly, or just solving an ad-hoc problem?

Ultimately, only you can make these sorts of calls.